# How to reveal dot files in finder?

Tags: finder, macos

In the finder, files that begin with a `.` (dot) are not being shown for me.

How can I configure the finder to reveal all files, including ones that begin with a dot?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Open your Terminal (`/Applications/Utilities`) then enter,

`defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES`

Then restart Finder by holding down Option and Control, or right-clicking on the Finder's icon in your Dock and choosing "Relaunch".

To revert this behavior, simply change the `YES` to `NO` in that `defaults` command.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not change the behaviour of finder in an Open File window, for example. But see abh's shortcut below

Answer (score 90):

A handy keyboard shortcut to reveal files that begin with a `.` (dot) in Finder is:

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>

This toggles `.` (dot) files to show/ hide without needing to restart Finder.

You can also define an alias to quickly toggle hidden files within Finder:

```
alias AllFilesTRUE='defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE; killall Finder'
alias AllFilesFALSE='defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE; killall Finder'
```

Comment: The keyboard shortcut is a great tip! I wish I could do that directly in Finder (not just in an "Open" window).

Comment: This is better.

Comment: I have confirmed that this works in any Finder window in Mojave :-)

Comment: I prefer this since I often don't want to see the dot files

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! It works in the finder too.

Comment: This also works in the System Information app, in the File Browser

Comment: @abh Where was this documented that you could learn of it?