# zshrc file invisible in finder but present in terminal

Tags: terminal, finder, zsh

When I give ls-a in my root folder I can actually see zshrc.
but when I open my root folder in finder using the `open .` command, It's not visible. Actually many files are missing.[image: Output when I give ls -a].As you can see the zshrc file is visible here. [image: Output when I give open.]I can't find it in the finder.

Comment: By default, the Finder does not show dot files. To change that, see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/250638/how-to-reveal-dot-files-in-finder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory):

> In computing, a hidden folder (sometimes hidden directory) or hidden file is a folder or file which filesystem utilities do not display by default when showing a directory listing.

The `ls` command, of course, is a directory listing. The `-a` option "do not ignore entries starting with ." ([`ls` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html))

So, yes the file is invisible, or hidden. But in the terminal, you are requesting to see all, including invisible or hidden, files.

Comment: Note that the Finder (and macOS GUI in general) hides files that start with "." *and/or* have the `hidden` flag set. That's why, for example, the Library folder (under your home folder) is hidden. To see flags including `hidden`, use `ls -lO`.